# Replacing part in object by dynamically traversing to it

Tags: javascript, path, traversal

Is there a way to dynamically traverse an object and replace a part with, for example, a new object?

Lets say I have this (extremely simplified) object:

```
persons = [{ 
    male: [{ name: 'sjv', age: 34 }, { name: 'jv', age: 62 }, { name: 'mlk', age: 28 }] }, { female: [{ name: 'hlk', age: 43 }, { name: 'pj', age: 65 }, { name: 'kj', age: 18 }] 
}]
```

Now I'm looking for a way to easily and quickly update a partial of the persons object at runtime. I'm able to conjure up a path that conceptually points to the partial i need to change.

Lets say I want to update the property with the path 'persons.female[1].age'
How would you do that?

Again ( ! ) the path is dynamic and changes at runtime.

This is how I find or can build the path:

```
        findPath = function (obj, partialID, path) {
            for (var key in obj) {
                if (typeof obj[key] === 'object') {
                    var tmp  = path + '.' + key;
                    this.findPartial(obj[key], partialID, tmp);
                }
                else if (typeof obj[key] !== 'function' && obj[key] === partialID) {
                    this.path = path;
                }
            }
            return;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're making this more complicated than it needs to be with your findPath function.  Why not just loop and find the object you want and change it?  E.g.

```
var key = 'jv';
persons.male.forEach(function(p){
    if(p.name === key)
        p.age++;
});
```